# How to remove physical path in main.js Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I get a problem to remove physical path in main.js, yesterday I get my result pentest, in my pentest recommend me to remove physical path in main.js (you can find main.js in assets/www/build after you decode your ionic .apk), this is an example of my physical path :

[image]

I try to look for an example to remove but I can't find it.

Please anyone help me to remove physical path. .

Thanks